# How to match user introduced hour in format HH:MM

Tags: python, date, try-catch

I'm trying to match a introduced user hour with 24 hours HH:MM format, not H:MM neither HH:M.

Here's mi code

```
def validateDate(date1, date2):
try:
    time_re = re.compile(r'^(1?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$')
    match(time_re, date1)
    match(time_re, date2)
except :
    print "Datos o formato incorrecto, deberia ser hh:mm \n"
```

Comment: What is now wrong with this? What happens when you run your program and where it goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re

def validateDate(date1, date2):
    try:
        time_re = re.compile(r'^(0[0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$')
        a=re.match(time_re, date1)
        b=re.match(time_re, date2)
        if a is None or b is None:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    except :
        print "foo"
        raise
```

There are several problems there.  First, your regexp is slightly wrong, allowing 9:33 instead of requiring 09:33. However, re.match does not raise an exception if it does not match. It returns a match group if there is a match, or None if there isn't.

Your generic exception clause is triggered probably because you have not imported re correctly.  Try adding raise to your exception handler and you will see it actually complaining about compile or match not found.

This is why you should never use Except: clause if you do not know what you are doing, as you will catch also syntactical errors in your code making it more difficult to debug.

My modified function returns True if both date1 and date2 are ok and False if either of them is wrong. Hope this helps.

Hannu